# regex capturing groups fails to capture multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern that I want to capture
G01 or G01-I006 or G01-I006-I1 or G01-I006-I1-R06 or G01-I006-I1-R06-F001

I want to have a capturing group if the input is G01-I006-I1-R06-F001
to capture G 01, I 006, I 1, R 06 and F 001

I came up with this pattern:

```
(([G|I|R|F])[0-9]{1,4}-?){1,}
```

But for G01-I006-I1-R06-F001 the capturing groups contain only F001

Comment: When you set a quantifier to the capturing group, you only get the last substring matched there, previous ones are lost. Use multiple matches, and push the submatches to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cycle between all the matches:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String input = "G01 G01-I006 G01-I006-I1 G01-I006-I1-R06 G01-I006-I1-R06-F001";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([GIRF])([0-9]{1,4})-?");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Run this pattern and then you will understand what I mean: (G)([0-9]{1,3})(?:-?(I)([0-9]{1,3}))?(?:-?(I)([0-9]{1,3}))?(?:-?(R)([0-9]{1,3}))?(?:-?(F)([0-9]{1,3}))?

Comment: I would like a more simplified version of it

Comment: @patentul: sorry, i had read too quick, try if the updated version may fit for your needs.

Comment: `[G|I|R|F]` matches a `|`. I think you wanted to write `[GIRF]`.

Comment: @stribizhev: thanks, i've used the patentul regex as starting point and miss it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
[A-Z]\d+
```

expects the parts to be A-Z followed by digits.

Comment: No need using parentheses here.

Answer (score 0):

No need Square Brackets In your pattern.

Try like this:

```
((G|I|R|F)[0-9]{1,4}-?){1,}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
([G|I|R|F])([0-9]{1,4})/g
```

Comment: It wont select anything